# Policy for deleting own answers

Tags: discussion, answers, policy

What is the policy, or what should the policy be, regarding own answers that are correct, but have no up-votes.

Obviously, if you have no up-votes, then nobody find your answer interesting or good enough, even if it is correct.

Should we then delete such answers, to clean up the database? Or should we let them be for the sake of completeness?

*EDIT*: Not enough answers to draw a final conclusion, but I will personally follow Stephan Lehmke’s recommendation. Therefore, I accept his answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd find it hard to say when this should occur. A popular answer might turn out to be too special or even erroneous much later, so its less popular sibling might be the only survivor.

Also a not so popular answer might become more useful when the application of a question broadens by linking duplicates to it.

So, personally, I'd say an answer should not be deleted (by the author) unless it is clearly wrong or is a clear duplicate of (or subsumed by) another answer.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes it happens that the answer is a no-brainer, e.g. update the problematic package, forgotten `;` at the end of a line in TikZ, etc. In such cases the answer is in fact a comment and it is hardly worth to bother converting it into a proper answer. IMHO these are candidates for deletion by the OP.